# Keystore file doesn't exist

Tags: android, xamarin, google-api, mono

I'm trying to get the SHA1 fingerprint so I can get an Google API key.
Im in the following directory:

> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home/bin

Then I execute the command from the google site :

> keytool -list -v -keystore mystore.keystore

But it gives this error:

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: mystore.keystore
java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: mystore.keystore
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:742)
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:340)
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:333)
```

I followed tutorials but I can't get it to work!
Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

BTW: I'm using a Macbook Pro with Xamarin Studio 5.5.2.

Comment: The problem could be you are just trying to run the command copying from somewhere and not knowing what is actually is ,,(that happened to me ;)  as well ), Once you know where and what it looks for , probably you would get the answer.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You said you are running the command from...

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home/bin
```

Is your keystore file in that directory as well? If not then you need to specify the path to the keystore file, e.g.

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/somefolder/mystore.keystore
```

The keystore used should be the one used to sign the app. For Xamarin debug builds this will be the debug keystore located at `/Users/[USERNAME]/.local/share/Xamarin/Mono\ for\ Android/debug.keystore`. The command on OSX for this would be...

```
keytool -list -v -keystore /Users/[USERNAME]/.local/share/Xamarin/Mono\ for\ Android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Or on Windows 7

```
keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Comment: I can't find my keystore, I'm not sure in what directory it is in.

Comment: The fingerprint you need for the Google API key needs to be generated from the keystore which is used to sign your app. For a Xamarin debug build, it uses its debug keystore. Your command for this would be `keytool -list -v -keystore /Users/[USERNAME]/.local/share/Xamarin/Mono\ for\ Android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android`, where [USERNAME] is your mac user.

Comment: I had to include "quotes" around the path name. Otherwise it gets confused with the space in the path.

Comment: Suppperrrr I tried 100 articles but was unable to locate. Thanx alot

Answer (score 97):

Linux & Mac command

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Will give you SHA1, SHA256, MD5 for default debug key. And it can be used for developing and debugging with google play services.

For publication certificate just follow https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html

Answer (score 19):

I faced the same issue, but resolved via following command:

```
keytool -exportcert -keystore C:\Users\<USERNAME>\.android\debug.keystore -list -v
```

**OS:** Windows 7

Answer (score 15):

I have windows 10, I went to the route

```
c:/Users/usuario/.android/
```

Inside directory, execute command:

```
keytool -exportcert -keystore debug.keystore -list -v
```

Must generate fingerprint:

```
SHA-1: 73:BE:1A:.......................
MDO: 73:BE:A1.........................
SHA-256: 3B:B8:98:...................
```

Comment: I am getting this error — 'keytool' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: asked me for the password is android
and it is worked thanks

Answer (score 11):

Linux or Mac or Windows, use complete path

Mac:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore /Users/username/.android/debug.keystore
-alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Linux (Ubuntu in my case):

```
keytool -list -v -keystore /home/username/.android/debug.keystore
-alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Windows:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\username\.android\debug.keystore
-alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

DO NOT FORGET TO REPLACE `username` BY YOURS⛑️ VERY IMPORTANT❗️

Hope it works for you!

Answer (score 10):

Please provide the complete path of debug.keystore. 
Example: C:/Users/myusername/.android/debug.keystore instead of ~/.android/debug.keystore

Answer (score 9):

In my case the `debug.keystore` is generated after the first run of the app on Android Studio

Comment: Yah same thing in my case

Answer (score 6):

I found this guide from **teamtreehouse** forum. hope it'll help you.

1) Open **Command Prompt** by pressing **Start+R** and typing cmd.exe.

2) Using **Windows Explorer**, find where your **JDK** directory is located (Usually Program Files >> Java) and copy the path.

3) In **Command Prompt**, type cd followed by the directory of your JDK’s bin directory. e.g: cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin is the command I use (Yours may vary).

4) Using Windows Explorer, find where your .android directory is located (Usually under Users >> `[YOUR WINDOWS USERNAME]`) and copy the path.

5) Now, use this command below:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore[PATH_TO_.ANDROID_DIRECTORY] -list -v
```

Replacing `[PATH_TO_.ANDROID_DIRECTORY]` with the path you copied. Note that you should be running this command in terminal/command prompt in your JDK’s bin directory (You did this in Step 3).

Mine is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin>keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\HoSiLuan\.android\debug.keystore -list -v`

Remember to use  `C:\Users\HoSiLuan\.android\debug.keystore` instead of `~/.android\debug.keystore`. I still got the error when type this shorten way.

You should then be prompted with the password as normal which you can enter (The password is android) . After that, you’ll see the list of certificates printed to the screen.

Comment: I did exactly what you said, and I still get the message "file does not exist"...

Comment: Mine is C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin>keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\HoSiLuan\.android\debug.keystore -list -v         <is the key part thanks>

Comment: found it in "C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\debug.keystore"

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. 
My error was

> keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist:/Users/[USER_NAME]/.android/debug.keystore java.lang.Exception: Keystore
>   file does not exist: /Users/[USER_NAME]/.android/debug.keystore 
>    at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:910)
>    at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:416)
>    at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:409)

I checked my /Users/[USER_NAME]/.android/ directory and I couldn't find `debug.keystore` file there.

**Reason**:

I used VSCODE and I did run my application only for iOS through iOS Simulator.

**Solution:**

I opened Android Studio and run my application for android with Android Emulator.

Then I got debug.keystore file in my .android/ directory.

Then I tried command below again:

```
keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

And it runs without any error.

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error in Windows 10 as well. But  sorted it and finally got SHA-1 Key.

I followed these steps

1.Open C drive and follow this path `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin` .

2.Inside bin folder open CMD and run command `keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:/Users/Username/.android/debug.keystore` . (Replace Username with your username).

3.Enter password as  `android` .

Answer (score 3):

If you are on Windows open command prompt and **RUN AS ADMINISTRATOR** then paste the line  `keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore`. That should work, it worked for me

Answer (score 3):

So I have found the solution.

On Windows, open cmd from start menu and write `cd C:\Users\put_here_your_username\.android` and then write
`keytool -list -v -keystore ".\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

I lived same problem on *Windows 10* and solved that problem with writing below command:

`keytool -list -keystore debug.keystore`

I think with some other commands java couldn't find debug.keystore file but interestingly with that command it works for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same Error
am using ubuntu 18.04

**Solution:**

Open terminal and navigate to `/home/{$user}/.android`

Then run the command

`keytool -list -v \ -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore`

You will be prompted to enter a keystore password enter `android`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I just ran the `keytool -list -v \ -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore`

Comment: Thanks bro , it worked in Windows 10 also. You saved my day

Comment: Don't know about the password is `android`. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 2):

Below command should work:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Answer (score 1):

last update for Mac & Ubuntu

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore  ~/.android/debug.keystore -list -v
```

Comment: not working, `keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Only one command is allowed: both -exportcert and -list were specified.`

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem, I found that I had .android folder inside another .android folder. **Make sure to find the right path of debug.keystore file on your system**

I used this command and it worked

keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\User.android.android\debug.keystore

Answer (score 1):

```
keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\%USERNAME%\.android\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Try this to get resolve from the problem

Answer (score 1):

in my case, keystore file was not generated at C:\Users\YourUserNameHere\.android\debug.keystore.

so i used below command to generate one and after that was able to get certificate fingerprint SHA1 & SHA256

android is the password used in below command

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore C:\Users\YourUserNameHere\.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Answer (score 1):

'**keytool -alias androiddebugkey
-keystore %USERPROFILE%/.android/debug.keystore -list -v -storepass android**'

when writing this code

'**keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: %USERPROFILE%.android\debug.keystore**'

You may get an error like .

It will ask you for the path to the 'debug.keystore' file.

[image]

Enter the path in the '%USERPROFILE%' field

as follows

```
keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\username\.android\debug.keystore 
-alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Hopefully it benefits your business

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows open command prompt and then Run it as an administration then paste this: keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%.android\debug.keystore

use password : android

then you will get SHA-1 and SHA-256 this worked smoothly for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install keytool on your system
   Keytool is included as part of the Java runtime. So by installing Java, you'll also have keytool in your system.

   To install Java, visit the [JAVA SE Downloads page](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/). Then, select the JDK Download link.
2. After that, add the keytool folder to your system `%PATH%` (on Windows). In order to run keytool from the command line, you need to add it to your system PATH. This step is required on Windows only.
3. Finally, run this command in a terminal, and don't forget to change the user name to your own:
   `keytool -list -v -keystore "c:\users\your_user_name\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android`

Answer (score 0):

Open CMD and navigate to Java bin folder for example:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_341\bin
```

Once you stand here then paste this:

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:/Users/*YOUR_PC_USERNAME*/.android/debug.keystore
```

**Do not forget to change to your own PC username** marked with * *YOUR_PC_USERNAME* *

Answer (score 0):

Double check that you are putting the correct address in my case I had two typos and that fixed it.

I had c:User instead of C:\Users\

Answer (score 0):

Find your debug.keystore file by searching (usually it is in .android) and then use this

> keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\u_name\ .android\debug.keystore"

- Use your own full path name not copy paste from anywhere.

It solved mine and this or some else solution will solve yours too.

Answer (score 0):

just put this given command in your package.json file and hit run yarn sha-keys

"sha-keys": "keytool -list -v -keystore ./android/App/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android",

Answer (score 0):

1. for mac
2. keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 (type on your terminal you fill all the things and say yes)
3. keytool (type on your terminal)
4. close the terminal
5. keytool -list -v 
   -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore (type on your terminal if you are using latest java it automaticaly save on .android may path is similar to like this [Storing /Users//.android/)
6. keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -storepass android (type on your terminal you can get sha1 key)