# Flutter - Cant get Google Signin Sha1 key

Tags: macos, flutter, android-studio, sha1

When ever I try to generate Sha1 key, I get this error.
Please note after fresh macOS BgSur installation, I only added flutter to path, installed xcode, android-studio and vscode.

**code I use**

```
keytool -list -v \
-alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

**Error I get**

```
/.android/debug.keystore
java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: 
/Users/nuaiman/.android/debug.keystore
at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:777)
at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:375)
at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:368)
```

Comment: Have you tried this?: https://www.programmersought.com/article/58881309665/

Comment: @Nuaiman Have a look on this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27037194/keystore-file-doesnt-exist