# Cant find android keystore on mac

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, android-keystore

this is the path to the keystore in visual studio for mac

[image: keystore]

when the keytool is excuted it says it can not find the file.

[image: terminal]

I am lost baffled and confused.  Any help would be most appreciated. I am trying to get SHA-1 fingerprint

Comment: does the file actually exist at that path?  Can you open it with `keytool`?

Comment: Yes the file does exist I can navigate to in finder

Comment: I will try to open it

Comment: @Jason I did down a KeyStore Explorer that was able to open the file thanks.  http://keystore-explorer.org/

Comment: So did you use it instead of using the Keytool to excute the command?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can check the official document about the [For Debug / Non-Custom Signed Builds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/signing/keystore-signature?tabs=macos#for-debug--non-custom-signed-builds) and use the following command to test the debug.keystore.

```
$ keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.local/share/Xamarin/Mono\ for\ Android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

And then you can read the official document about the [For Release / Custom Signed Builds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/signing/keystore-signature?tabs=macos#for-release--custom-signed-builds) and use the release keystore's path to do that.

Finnally, you can refer to this case which had the same error about [Keystore file doesn't exist in the mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27037194/keystore-file-doesnt-exist). You can try the accepted answer or the others in it.